# ../lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found

Tags: debian, glibc

I'm running a debian wheezy (7.8) box and I just ran into a problem with an application that needs `GLIBC_2.12'.

The glibc-linking seems confusing to me. Maybe someone can enlighten me?

The program uses libldap, which seems to be depending on libc. when I run the application, I get

```
/opt/ecosims/server/ecosimsserver: ../lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2)
```

looking at my installed packages, it seems that libc-version 2.13 should be there:

`ii  libc-bin                              2.13-38+deb7u8 
ii  libc-client2007e                      8:2007f~dfsg-2 
ii  libc-dev-bin                          2.13-38+deb7u8 
ii  libc6:amd64                           2.13-38+deb7u8 
rc  libc6:i386                            2.13-38+deb7u8

ii  libc6-dev:amd64                       2.13-38+deb7u8 
ii  libc6-i386                            2.13-38+deb7u8 
rc  libc6-i686:i386                       2.13-38+deb7u8`

The output of 'ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2' gives:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa6fde000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f82430a6000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f8242e90000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f8242c74000)
    libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26 (0x00007f82429b4000)
    libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11 (0x00007f8242735000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8242518000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f824218d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8241f89000)
    libtasn1.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3 (0x00007f8241d77000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8241b60000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f824194e000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f824174a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f824352d000)
```

To me it looks like libldap should be using /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 which is a symlink to version 2.13:

```
ls -al /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.13.so
```

So why does the error message talk about ../lib/libc.so.6?

Maybe related:
'ldd -v /usr/bin/gcc' says:

```
  libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8c7e0c8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8c7dd3d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8c7e371000)

    Version information:
    /usr/bin/gcc:
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.11) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6:
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
            ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
            ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Where does the GLIBC_2.11 come from?

I must admit I don't know much about dynamic linking. Any help or hint would be great!

EDIT: ldd -v  output:

Here is the output of ldd -v ecosims. Everything seems to be linking agains `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

The only component requiring GLIBC_2.12 is libldap.

```
./ecosimsserver:
            libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
            libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
            libgcrypt.so.11 (GCRYPT_1.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
            libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
            libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

...

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2:
            libgcrypt.so.11 (GCRYPT_1.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11
            libresolv.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
            libgnutls.so.26 (GNUTLS_1_4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26
            libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
            libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
            libsasl2.so.2 (SASL2) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.12) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

And according to `apt` libc should be version 2.13.

Comment: Is there a `libc.so.6` somewhere beneath `/opt/ecosims`?

Comment: It seems that your application loads additional libraries from its own path. What is the output of `ldd -v /opt/ecosims/server/ecosimsserver` (if that's a binary, otherwise `ldd -v` on the binary that it executes)? What about `ls -l /opt/ecosims/lib`?

Comment: I couldn't find libc anywhere in the application directory. ldd tells me that libc is supposed to be in /lib/x86_64...

Comment: I have added more information in the original post